# Unable to login when using Tor

Tags: login

There are certain sites that does not allow the user to login when they are using Tor. Why do we face this issue?

We can surf these sites, but cannot login using the Username and password.

It works fine when we are not accessing that site via Tor.

Comment: Doesn't logging in via Tor defeat the purpose of using an anonymous network?  Some websites don't allow connections or logins from anonymous proxies.

Comment: @ raz - I can login to this site via some proxy sites but not Tor.

Comment: @raz perhaps you want to be pseudonymous, but not anonymous. Think of bitcoin creator Satoshi Nakamoto.

Answer (score 3):

Every site is a server offering a *service*. It does so under whatever conditions it wishes to enforce; each server is its own master. If a server owner does not want to allow login for connections that come from Tor, then the server can certainly just do what you observe. It is in their technical possibilities, and there is no law against it either.

Some servers want to avoid any legal insecurity; for instance, if the server hosts some sort of blog with comments, the server owner may wish to keep logs of incoming IP addresses, so that he may have something to give to law enforcement agencies if some comments happen to fall within the field of said agencies (to take an over-the-top, caricatural example, imagine comments calling for pro-pedophile terrorism and holy war against the US President). This is one of the reasons why a server owner may wish not to talk any further with Tor-powered clients. Other reasons may be a perceived "higher risk" from such connections because Tor users are *obviously* shifty individuals with no morals, and armed with all sorts of cyber-malviruswares that kill puppies.

Of course there is no "official" list of Tor exit nodes, but some people maintain such lists automatically (e.g. see [here](https://www.dan.me.uk/dnsbl)).

Answer (score 1):

When using Tor, you get an IP address from one of its exit nodes. This is probably a well known IP address. Tor is used by anyone wanting to be anonymous, including people who want to troll forums. Many sites therefor block these IP-adresses.

It can get worse. I've ran Tor on a server at home, not an exit node of course, and I know at least one big site that blocks my home IP. Apparently my IP address is listed on one of the Tor black lists.

So while using Tor, in the future you might find that you are being blocked even when not using Tor.